# How do I set multiple files to one folder for reading and writing files?

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a list of 10 different txt.files that im trying to compile into one file. My first task in order to do so is to set a file path to one folder (main folder) for reading and writing files.

```
file_path = Path.home()/"main_folder"

with file_path.open(mode="r", encoding="UTF-8", newline="") as file:
     reader = csv.reader(file, "delimiter=","")
```

but it does not seem to be working, any idea how I can fix this issue? or the solution to the code would be helpful.

The Error that shows up:  "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 1117, in open
return self._accessor.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors,
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\name\project'

Comment: I think you have to define your `file_path` as `Path.home() + "/main_folder"`

Comment: @GeekyQuentin `pathlib` seems to handle the use case provided by OP.

Comment: "it does not seem to be working" isn't helpful: what is the error message? Please [edit] the post to include the problem that you're facing. Also, please provide a [mre]: what is Path? Where have you defined it?

Comment: Try looking at [How do I open multiple files in Python and read all the contents of it and close it?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-open-multiple-files-in-Python-and-read-all-the-contents-of-it-and-close-it-Particularly-calling-every-file-in-a-loop-and-read-its-contents-and-process-it-before-closing-I-have-already-seen-an-answer-for-C)

Comment: Your code is trying to open a file named `main_folder` in your home directory. That is probably not what you wanted. Also, your call to `csv.reader` should be: `csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")` (note that you have too many quotes on your call, and you are sending a completely different set of parameters to the the function)